# Properties of periodic Sturm-Liouville Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Consider the Regular Sturm Liouville(RSLP) problem

$$(p(x)y’)’+(q(x)+\lambda r(x))y=0$$ where $p,q$ and $r$ are functions such that $p$ has continuous derivative, $q$ and $r$ are continuous, and $p(x)>0$ and $r(x)>0$ for all $x$ on a real interval $a\leq x\leq b$ and $\lambda $ is a parameter independent of $x$ and with boundary conditions
$$A_1y(a)+A_2y’(a)=0$$

$$B_1y(b)+B_2y(b)=0$$

I know properties of this regular Sturm Liouville problems as follows( Given in Shepley L. Ross Differential Equations)

$1$. Eigen values of RSLP are reals and can be arrange in an increasing order.

$2$. Eigen values of RSLP are simple.

$3$. Eigen function $\phi_n(x)$ corresponding to $n$-th eigen value $\lambda_n$ has exactly $n-1$-zeros in the open interval $(a,b)$.

$4$. Eigen functions corresponding to different eigen values are orthogonal with respect to weight function $r$ on $[a,b]$.

Now I only know that for Periodic Strum Liouville problem eigen values many not be simple I.e. there many be two linearly independent eigen functions corresponding to an eigen value . **I want to know whether all others $3$ properties written above are true for periodic Sturm Liouville problem**. By a periodic Sturm Liouville problem  I mean the above differential equation with boundary conditions $y(a)=y(b), y’(a)=y’(b)$ and one more condition as $p(a)=p(b)$.Thank you .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your boundary conditions are $y(a)=y(b)$ and $y'(a)=y'(b)$ with $p(a)=p(b)$ then

1. there are infinitely many eigenvalues $-\infty<\lambda_0<\lambda_1\leq \lambda_2\leq \ldots$.
2. For $\lambda_0$ there is unique eigenfuntion $\phi_0$. If $\lambda_{2i+1}<\lambda_{2i+2}$ then there are unique eigenfunctions $\phi_{2i+1},\phi_{2i+2}$.
3. If $\lambda_{2i+1}=\lambda_{2i+2}$ then there are two independent eigenfunctions $\phi_{2i+1},\phi_{2i+2}$.
4. If $\phi_i$ and $\phi_j$ correspond to distinct $\lambda_i$ and $\lambda_j$ then they are orthogonal.
5. The set of all eigenfunctions forms a basis of corresponding space.
6. Furthermore, $\phi_0$ has no roots in $[a,b]$, $\phi_{2i+1},\phi_{2i+2}$ have exactly $2i+1$ roots in $[a,b)$.

Proof is given (as well as some more general cases) in Coddington and Levinson, Theory of ODE, in Chapter 8 and exercises.